# MYSQL updating with condition

Tags: php, mysql, database

Good afternoon, I've been searching for a way to update a table with different conditions and with one row only. I understand i can use the method "case" but its only updating the last row.

```
UPDATE inscription SET
classification= CASE WHEN id_inscription =1 THEN 1 END,
classification= CASE WHEN id_inscription =17 THEN 2 END,
classification= CASE WHEN id_inscription =18 THEN 3 END
WHERE id_inscription BETWEEN 1 AND 20;
```

I'm not sure if there is other way without using the "else" condition or if it is a query error.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a single `case` with multiple conditions. That is how it is meant to be used

```
UPDATE inscription 
SET classification = CASE WHEN id_inscription =  1 THEN 1 
                          WHEN id_inscription = 17 THEN 2     
                          WHEN id_inscription = 18 THEN 3 
                     END
WHERE id_inscription BETWEEN 1 AND 20;
```

Comment: Ohh i see my mistake now, I'm not used to work with the Case condition forgot how it must be done. Worked perfectly, thank you very much!